# How to create dynamic form in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create one dynamic form which contains question answer set and questions are different for every user. There are 5 questions out of this user have to answer at least 3 questions. In the set of 5 questions, the first user may get the set question which required 1 textfield 2 drops down and 2 radio buttons in the same way the second user may get 3 textfield 1 drop down and 1 radio button. What approach I should have to follow to achieve this?

I tried to create a table view. In the cell, I specified one label to render a question and one blank view which will be filled later on the basis where the question required text field or radio button or drop down. But with this case, I am not able to maintain which question I get answered because if I make textfield or checkbox's user interaction unable the didselectrowatindexpath method is not getting called even tried to mapping with delegate but this one is also not suitable for me because I have so many cases to manage as an answer field.

Comment: What about ViewModels and corresponding UITableCells? Let 'em do the job. If a question is answered or not either depends on didSelectRowAtIndexPath or form values.

Comment: create stackview with scrollview add your all control(set tag to every control) into stackview based on users, dont do with tableview you may face many problem

Comment: Facing lots of difficulties with table view don't want to go for the table approach

Comment: Have a look at [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka). It's extremely flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different implementations. What I would do is:-

- Distinguish the **Question Types** based on the UI(as per your case)
- Add a **questionType enum** in QuestionModel class
- Will create a different cell for each question type
- Use that particular cell for each question type
- Even in future any new **Qustion Type** has come, add one more case in enum and create one more cell

My Implementation will go something like this for QuestionModel class:-

```
Class Question {
 enum Type {
  case type1, type2 .....
  func cellIdentifier() -> String {
   switch self {
    case type1:
         return "type1"
    //Handle all cases

   }
  }
 }

 var type: Type

}
```

Controller class will be something like this:-

```
Class Controller: UIViewController {
 var questions = [Question]()

//Table view delegate method

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let questionAtIndexPath = questions[indexPath.row]
  let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: questionAtIndexPath.type.cellIdentifier(), for: indexPath)
  cell.configureWith(questionAtIndexPath)
  return cell
 }

}
```

Comment: I am getting what kind of question I have to render even I am able to manage UI dynamically but when it comes to extracting answers with the same dynamic field it creating the problem because I used the same component for several times

Comment: Handle it in UITableViewCell.....Update the Question object for answers passed to the cell(i.e. Add property for answers)......Even though the cell used is same, the Question object passed will be different in cellForRowAtIndexPath....On submit button click in Controller process the array of Question Object for answers

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main task you have is to create a dynamic form where you have different objects depending on the required question. So, do this first:

1. Create individual tableCells like one containing a label for the question and a textfield for the answer or checkbox's to answer the question. The label will be common for every tableCell.
2. Connect the required delegates or IBOutlets with the objects
3. Create closure in table cells and handle the data when user completed answering the question.
4. Finally save the data collected by the closures call backs in **TableViewcellforRowAtIndexpath** and use them as per required.

Comment: With table view not able to maintain a pair of questions and answered questions even it is not reaching to didselectrowatindexpath because my current component have active with user interaction (like I am entering a value in the text filed which have active user interaction that's why not reaching to didselectrowatindexpath there for not getting which cell is selected and which questions are getting answered)